# query regarding the error occuring during installation of cdo package (climate data operator)

Tags: make

I want to install a package called cdo (climate data operator) in my Ubuntu. While trying to do so I am unable run the command `make`, `make file` etc and the installation can't succeed.

I am attaching a copy of terminal where the error is shown:

```
ansa@ansa-Inspiron-3542:~$ cd cdo-1.7.1
ansa@ansa-Inspiron-3542:~/cdo-1.7.1$ ls
acinclude.m4     cdo.spec     config.log    COPYING  m4           OPERATORS
aclocal.m4       cdo.spec.in  configure     doc      Makefile.am  README
AUTHORS          ChangeLog    configure.ac  INSTALL  Makefile.in  src
cdo.settings.in  config       contrib       libcdi   NEWS         test
ansa@ansa-Inspiron-3542:~/cdo-1.7.1$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
configure: setting up libtool
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking for g++... no
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
checking for ar... (cached) ar
checking for ld... /usr/bin/ld
checking for nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking for ar... (cached) ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... false
checking for objdump... (cached) objdump
checking for strip... (cached) strip
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether : accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of :... none
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/home/ansa/cdo-1.7.1':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
ansa@ansa-Inspiron-3542:~/cdo-1.7.1$ sudo apt get-install cdo
[sudo] password for ansa: 
E: Invalid operation get-install
ansa@ansa-Inspiron-3542:~/cdo-1.7.1$
```

I am a beginner in Ubuntu and don't understand it. Please let me know what the problem actually is.

Comment: Configure script shows you an error: `C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check`. Here's the possible solution: http://askubuntu.com/q/509663 . Also you should run `make` after `./configure`, not `apt-get install`. Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) before starting your compilation.

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure is you have misplaced dash in your last command.

You typed:

```
sudo apt get-install cdo
```

You should have typed:

```
sudo apt-get install cdo
```

---

It seems the command above is sufficient, ie. no need to download source and run `make`. But it did not mess up anything.